# How can I represent three axes in a processing sketch?

Tags: graph, arduino, processing

I have an arduino sketch that i uploaded to my arduino board. It is interfaced with an mpu 9250 (IMU) and i am getting data out in multiple formats. One of the forms that I'm receiving is in the (x,y,z) format. Basically what I want to do is map out each axis value onto the same graph with different colors for each one. I am using Processing to visually represent the data, however, I am quite new to it. I have figured out how to create a graph but I'm not sure how I should send my data out so that the processing sketch can discern which value is for which axis. Does anybody have some experience in this? Could you give me a tip as to how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you are asking how best to transfer the IMU data from the Arduino to Processing.

The MPU9250 is a 9-axis IMU and raw data is 16 bits for all sensors (looks like the magnetometer might actually be 14 bits, but no matter). Therefore, if you are reading *all* the raw data into Processing, you need to transfer nine 16 bit values. Assuming you are using a serial connection between the Arduino and Processing, you are limited to 8 bit words, so each value requires two bytes.

Basically, convert each 16 bit IMU value into two bytes, and send them all at once in an 18 byte string (and maybe a validation byte or two for good measure, extra bytes also help with delineating the beginning of a packet). On the Processing end, reassemble the bytes and convert them back to integer values.